# Ant task replace text escape dollar

Tags: java, regex, ant

I want to replace `unfiled$public` with `unfiled\$public` and I'm using the following ant task -

```
 <replaceregexp match="unfiled$public" replace="unfiled\$public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
        <fileset dir="my_dir" />
    </replaceregexp>
```

but this is not doing the trick. I got to know that $ has to be escaped. I've tried this also without results -

```
 <replaceregexp match="unfiled\\$public" replace="unfiled\\\\\$public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
        <fileset dir="my_dir" />
    </replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<replaceregexp match="unfiled$$public" replace="unfiled\$$public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
    <fileset dir="my_dir" />
</replaceregexp>
```

As some compilers say to escape **$** with double **$$**. If this will not work you may try to leave **replace** untouched like: `replace="unfiled\$public"` and only escape the **match**:

```
<replaceregexp match="unfiled\$public" replace="unfiled\&#36;public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
        <fileset dir="my_dir" />
    </replaceregexp>
```

Comment: Using the second one its matching since I tried giving a dummy word in replace. But when I use `unfiled\$public` in replace it gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference`

Comment: @jacksparrow007 try using `unfiled\\$$public` or `unfiled\$$public`

Comment: @jacksparrow007 I'm not sure how about ant, but in java you should use quoteReplacement to suppress the meaning of `$` and then using `unfiled\$public` should work for you. See this doc, it should help: [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String))

Comment: @jacksparrow007 any progress?

Comment: Is there an equivalent of quoteReplacement in ant? I've tried every combination of $ and \ mentioned on this thread.

Comment: @jacksparrow007 I don't think so, but I have edited my answer, use `&#36;` instead of `$` in the replace string it should work, if not try to escape `\ ` as well using `\\ `. If it does work you might need this in the future [The ASCII Character Set](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You (most likely) don't need to double escape the backslashes, as they are used in a XML string (which have other escape rules, like `&amp;`, etc).

So try:

```
<replaceregexp match="unfiled\$public" replace="unfiled\$public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
    <fileset dir="my_dir" />
</replaceregexp>
```

Comment: @jacksparrow007, what replace do you get from the code above? `unfiled\$public` could work as replacement, if not try `unfiled\\$public` or `unfiled$$public`.

Comment: I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference` error for each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<replaceregexp match="unfiled$public" replace="unfiled\\$public" flags="gs" byline="false" >
            <fileset dir="my_dir" />
        </replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the replace attribute the dollar sign has to be written as **`\\\$`** since the dollar sign has to be escaped in the regular expression replace part resulting to `\$` and for Ant the two characters must be escaped again: `\\` + `\$`.